# How return to list in MVC 5 - CODE FIRST

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I need help to return a list. I am wanting to return pagination, search and grid using Jquery Grid MVC, but throws me error. This is my model:

```
namespace PedidosOnline.Models
{
    public class JqueryGrid
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string sNombre { get; set; }
    }
}

public class JqueryGridModel
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public List<JqueryGrid> GetPlayers(int? page, int? limit, string sortBy, string direction, string searchString, out int total)
    {
        List<JqueryGrid> all = db.JqueryGrids.ToList();
        //string sql = "Select * from JqueryGrid";

        var getJqueryGridToReturn = all.Select(S => new { ID = S.ID, sNombre = S.sNombre });

        total = all.Count();
        var records = (from p in db.JqueryGrids
                       select new JqueryGrid
                       {
                           ID = p.ID,
                           sNombre = p.sNombre
                       }).AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
        {
            records = records.Where(p => p.sNombre.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(direction))
        {
            if (direction.Trim().ToLower() == "asc")
            {
                records = SortHelper.OrderBy(records, sortBy);
            }
            else
            {
                records = SortHelper.OrderByDescending(records, sortBy);
            }
        }

        if (page.HasValue && limit.HasValue)
        {
            int start = (page.Value - 1) * limit.Value;
            records = records.Skip(start).Take(limit.Value);
        }

        return records.ToList();
    }
```

and error is:

> The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query return to list.

Example:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3ff6df/jquery-grid-with-Asp-Net-mvc/